# Re-calculate the confusion matrix from performance metrics

Tags: confusion-matrix

I am thinking to find the corresponding confusion matrix (binary classification) given some metrics (such as accuracy, sensitivity, precision, f1-score).

I know it is easy to find the confusion matrix from ground-truth and predicted labels. However, in my case, I don't have the predicted labels.

For example, I have

```
acc, sen, pre, f1_score =   68.00,  51.28,  80.00,  62.50
```

Is there a way to find the respective confusion matrix?

Comment: I have solved this by using Grid-Search strategy to fill up the confusion matrix elements. However, for large sample size, this solution is not advisable :).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can recover the confusion matrix (for binary classification), but you need to know the original number of positive (`P`) and negative (`N`) examples.

For example, if you know you have `N = 6` and `P = 4`, and know the sensitivity is `sen = 0.75` then you can plug them into the equation for sensitivity to get the number of true positives (`TP`):

```
sen  = TP / P
0.75 = TP / 4
TP   = 3
```

Now if you know the accuracy is `acc = 0.699`, you can solve for the number of true negatives (`TN`):

```
acc   = (TP + TN) / (P + N)
0.699 = (3  + TN) / (4 + 6)
TN    = 4
```

Which gives you enough to reconstruct the confusion matrix:

```
      TN    (N - TN)

(P - TP)    TP
```

---

Here is an example to help demonstrate this:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, recall_score, confusion_matrix

y_true = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]) # N = 6, P = 4
y_pred = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])

accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
# 0.69999
recall_score(y_true, y_pred)
# 0.75    i.e., recall is sensitivity
confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
# array([[4, 2],
#        [1, 3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much @Alexander L. Hayes, that is much easier than Grid-Search,

```
gTruth = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]

N = len(np.where(np.array(gTruth)==0)[0])
P = len(np.where(np.array(gTruth)==1)[0])
conf_mat = np.zeros((2,2))

acc_1 = 0.699
sen_1 = 0.75
TP = round(sen_1*P)
TN = round((acc_1*(N+P))-TP)
FP = N-TN
FN = P-TP

conf_mat[0,0] = TN
conf_mat[0,1] = FP
conf_mat[1,0] = FN
conf_mat[1,1] = TP

acc = ((TP+TN)/(TP+TN+FP+FN))
sen = (TP/(TP+FN))
spe = (TN/(TN+FP))
try:
    pre = (TP/(TP+FP))
except: 
    pre = 0.0
try:
    f1 = (2 * (pre * sen) / (pre + sen))
except:
    f1 = 0.0

print(conf_mat)
```